# Using a Microstrategy Prompt Answer twice

Tags: analytics, data-analysis, microstrategy

I'd like to know if a Microstrategy Prompt answer can be used twice. That is , I'd like to prompt the user once for an attribute value , and use the same answer in two different filters.

For instance , suppose I'm prompting to check whether Country A is equal to a Country C ( chosen by the user through a prompt) , is it possible for me to use the same answer(country C) to filter out cases where a Country B is equal to Country C

All help is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you will use the same prompt object in both filters you will be prompted only once.